# How to import existing iCloud contacts into Salesforce.

Tags: import, salesforce, icloud, contacts

I am needing to import iCloud contacts into Salesforce and was wondering if this is possible and if so, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Flagged as too broad

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before for a client.  You have to export all your iCloud contacts to vcards.  Then you have to find a tool that will convert vcards to csvs.

[Export iCloud to CSVs](https://www.maketecheasier.com/export-icloud-contacts-csv/)